# Closing Durandal modal

Tags: modal-dialog, durandal, hottowel

I have a Hottowel application and a Durandal modal dialog for creating a new entity. In it's viewmodel I have `create` and `cancel` functions, which both call `close` on success. The problem is that modal doesn't close when I call `close` from another function. It does close when I call it directly.

The code:

```
var close = function () {
    dialog.close(this);
};

var cancel = function () {
    datacontext.cancelChanges();
    close();
};

var create = function () {
    return datacontext.saveChanges()
        .then(close);
};
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of whole model? It's hard to tell what can be wrong looking only at these functions as they seems pretty fine.

Comment: You are forgetting that the context of `this` changes depending on how the close function is called. You need to make sure that `this` is your viewmodel; otherwise you will never get it to close.

Comment: You are right, but the results are still strange... Debugging showed that when I all close on it's own, `this` is a `Window` object whose `getDialog()` method returns the dialog. Calling close from another function makes `this` a `Window` object whose `getDialog`method returns `undefined`... Beats me... Anyway, calling `vm.close()` resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean it doesn't work when you call it from another function?  Are you sure that your context is still the same when you are calling it?

```
var close = function () {
    var self = this;
    dialog.close(self);
};
```

Try to update your close function to this and if it still isn't closing then could you please explain *where* you are calling it that it isn't closing from?  From inside the same view model, from another view model, which function, etc...

Comment: One can also call `app.close(self)` (which is just a convenience method which calls `dialog.close(self)`)